# Can I take either string or IEnumerable<T>, where T is string or IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a utility method that processes a collection of strings, let's say:

```
    public static string MyJoin(this IEnumerable<string> strings)
    {
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, strings);
    }
```

I'd like to be able to also process `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` and `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>>` and so on, all of them in this way:

```
    public static string MyJoin(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> strings)
    {
        return strings.Select(x => x.MyJoin()).MyJoin();
    }

    public static string MyJoin(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>> strings)
    {
        return strings.Select(x => x.MyJoin()).MyJoin();
    }
```

Is there any way I can elegantly express this without hardcoding all the possible levels I might want to use?

- I've tried to do it with generics, but I just can't figure out the right constraints (if there are any).
- I'd also like to avoid declaring a new type, if at all possible.
- Performance, on the other hand, is not critical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partly inspired by Stefan's answer, I've reached a working solution that compiles without generics and (unfortunately) with mostly runtime type checking:

```
    public static string MyJoin(this IEnumerable<string> strings)
    {
        return string.MyJoin(Environment.NewLine, strings);
    }
    public static string MyJoin(this IEnumerable<object> items)
    {
        if (items.All(x => x is string))
            return items.Cast<string>().MyJoin();

        if (items.All(x => x is IEnumerable<object>))
            return items.Cast<IEnumerable<object>>().Select(x => x.MyJoin()).MyJoin();

        throw new InvalidOperationException("The argument was not a nested enumerable of strings.");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with `IEnumerable<T>` and strings, because a string is an `IEnumerable<T>`, where T is `char`.

Static implementation using multiple overloads:

```
public static string MyJoin(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>> items)
{
    return items.SelectMany(x => x).MyJoin();
}

public static string MyJoin(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> items)
{
    return items.SelectMany(x => x).MyJoin();
}

public static string MyJoin(this IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, strings);
}
```

You cannot have a single generic method and "unwrap" the generic argument dynamically.

Implementation using reflection:

```
public static string MyJoin<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)
    {
        return items.Cast<string>().MyStringJoin();
    }
    var innerIEnumerableType = typeof(T).GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsGeneric() 
        && x.GetGenericType() == typeof(IEnumerable<>);
    if (innerIEnumerableType != null)
    {
        // create generic method to 
        var method = typeof(ThisType).GetMethod("MyJoin", /* some flags */)
            .MakeGenericMethod(innerIEnumerableType.GetGenericArguments().First())

        // recursive call to generic method
        return items.Select(x => (string)method.Invoke(null, x)).MyStringJoin();
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Type is not a (nested) enumarable of strings")
}

public static string MyStringJoin(this IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, strings);
}
```

To be honest, reflection isn't useful here. Why use generics, if it isn't typesafe anyway? At the end you could just as well use non-generic `IEnumerable`. It's much easier to implement. See Denis Itskovich's solution, he managed to write down what I actually tried to do.

Comment: It won't compile because there is no Select extension method for non generic IEnumerable. Of course it's still possible to call Enumerable.Select via reflection...

Comment: True. I fixed it. You can only cast the items to object to get an `IEnumerablte<T>` without knowing T.

Comment: Fixed version also won't compile because there is no Cast method for T (which is not bound with constraints). In my opinion the only way is to use reflection.

Comment: I think you meant to cast it to `(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>)` before calling select and object (in the second `if`)? Otherwise it doesn't compile. However, calling it on a simple `IEnumerable<string>[]` (enumerable of enumerable of string) misses both conditions and hits the exception. =/

Comment: Yes, you are right. It doesn't work like this. The recursive call has to use the correct generic argument T, because T is tested for its type. This requires reflection. It's probably too complicated. Using separate methods is much easier and more type safe. Implementation with pure "generic magic" isn't possible. You could switch to IEnumerable (without T) to make it easier to implement and less type safe. (See Denis Itskovich solution)

Answer (score 2):

Based on Stefan's solution, simplified and compilation-fixed version

```
public static string MyJoin(this IEnumerable items)
{
    if (items is IEnumerable<string>)
    {
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, (IEnumerable<string>)items);
    }
    if (items is IEnumerable<IEnumerable>)
    {
        return items.Cast<IEnumerable>().Select(x => x.MyJoin())).MyJoin();
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Type is not a (nested) enumarable of strings");
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. I didn't try to remove the generic completely. But this is what I actually wanted to do. I replaced my answer with a pure type safe overload-based solution and a overly-complicated reflection based solution ...

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having an `IEnumerable` of an unknown type, what you're really trying to do here is create a tree based structure.  The most effective way of doing this is to create a `Node` class that can represent a value an its children.

```
public class Node
{
    public Node(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Children = Enumerable.Empty<Node>();
    }
    public Node(string value, IEnumerable<Node> children)
    {
        Value = value;
        Children = children;
    }
    public string Value { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<Node> Children { get; private set; }
}
```

This is now a *much* easier structure to traverse.  Here is a general purpose tree traversal method which we can apply to this case:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(T item, 
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childSelector)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>();
    stack.Push(item);
    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var next = stack.Pop();
        yield return next;
        foreach (var child in childSelector(next))
            stack.Push(child);
    }
}
```

---

```
var allValues = Traverse(rootNode, node => node.Children)
    .Select(node => node.Value);
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the SelectMany extension method.